# Cannot clone nRF52840 to reproduce low deep sleep current

Tags: arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy, nrf52

I currently have firmware that can reach an average deep sleep current of ~130uA. I can reach this level reproducibly on one of the boards I have.

[successful deep sleep](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fglGL.png)

Trouble is, when I try to clone this chip onto other chips using the nRF Programmer (Connect) app, I get extremely high power consumption, average of ~20mA at all times, seems the device doesn't reach deep sleep properly. Tried this on several other boards, so I don't believe it's simply a problem of something shorting. Strangely, the application just runs fine, the current is just several times normal for the same functionality.

[unsuccessful deep sleep](https://i.stack.imgur.com/44dgy.png)

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can truly clone the flash of one device, onto another? Clearly the "save as file" on nRF Connect isn't doing this. Erasing all and reuploading, starting from a blank chip and writing,

FYI I'm using the nRF52840 module by Raytac (MDBT50Q), implemented on a custom board. This board SHOULD be capable of going down to ~33uA, which I have observed in the past with this very board. By some combination of erasing all, reprogramming, setting the 3.3V logic level(nrfjprog --memwr 0x10001304 --val 5), etc,

Comment: Stackoverflow is for programming related questions. Your question is better for [electronics.stackexchange](https://electronics.stackexchange.com), but even you want to post there, you need to provide more detail info such as schematic diagram of your custom board, what you did to put the device in low power mode(a device will not go into low battery mode unless you explicitly set it so), your current post provide no information at all for people to help you.

Comment: Also consider asking over at the [Nordic DevZone](https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/f/nordic-q-a), the developers from nordic might be able to help

Comment: Thank you all for your replies, in the future I'll be sure to post at Nordic as well as electronics.stackexchange, as you're right this would better be suited there.

Answer (score 0):

For posterity, I did actually find the solution! For anyone else in a similar boat to me, the winning command is:

```
nrfjprog.exe  --readcode --readuicr --readram [filename.hex]
```

Apparently, the --readram was the winning flag, as without it the sketch simply doesn't run at the same current consumption for whatever reason. But now, I can reproducibly image and transfer identical firmware, which was what I was after.